# How do I find all the maximal subgroups of group like $G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm actually looking to find the Frattini subgroup, $\Phi(G)$. I think finding the maximal subgroups and then their intersection is the method I ought to adopt hence the question about finding those.

Although, I'm not sure if it would be easier to find all the non-generators of $G$? How would one go about finding all the non-generators?

Comment: Perhaps it'd be a good idea first to write the group as $\;G=\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_{35}=\Bbb Z_{20}\times\Bbb Z_7\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Because it's easier then to find the subgroups with prime index?

Comment: Yes, though I was thinking in a different direction...but it actually boils down to the same: subgroups with prime index, and it is as easy this or that way.

Comment: For example, with $\;\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_{35}\;$ we can certainly see a maximal group of index $\;2\;$  say, namely $\;\left\{(2,z)\;/ z\in\Bbb Z_{35}\right\}\;$ , and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm struggling with another similar problem. If $G=\mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, then how do you find the maximal subgroups? I can use GAP to find them, but I need to be able to do this in a written exam. Mainly the problem is that what do you do about finding a subgroup that may not be cyclic?

Comment: Only  subgroups of index $\;2,\,5\;$ count, right? Well this means subgroups of order $\;20,\,50\;$ , so taking $\;\Bbb Z_{10}=\{0,1,2,...,9\}\pmod{10}\;$ , we can take for example $\;H:=\{0,\,5\}\times\Bbb Z_{10}\;$ . Observe that each factor, being a cyclic group, has one *unique* subgroup of every order dividing $\;10\;$ . Take it from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The maximal subgroups of a finite abelian group are exactly the subgroups of prime index.

Comment: Can you please also hint at finding the non-generators, because it seems like finding the indices of each subgroup is going to take a lot of time in an exam type situation?

Comment: @Maria: "a lot of time"?? Your group has order $\;2^2\cdot5\cdot7\;$ , so the maximal subgroups have all index $\;2,\,5,\,\text{or}\;\;7\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I was individually finding the subgroups and checking their index... you're saying that's not the right approach?

Comment: @Maria You need **only** the subgroups of prime index! There aren't lots of options here, are there?

Comment: No, you're right, there aren't many. I'm going to find $\Phi(G)$ now, given all of your hints.

Comment: ... and this answer's excellent hint @Maria

Comment: Sorry, thanks to @lhf as well.